# Where will be store all my local database tables records into elasticsearch server after dumping?

Tags: elasticsearch

> At present I am using elasticsearch-1.0.0.Beta2 for quick search the
>   records.But while dumping I have 20000 recods in user table. But in
>   elasticsearch server(http://www.domain.com) I can see only fifty
>   records.But all records are dumping(means when I using this 
>   http://www.domain.com/index/type/id 
>   (http://www.domain.com/salambc/Question/51f9ac9024c8ce5261f4ee55))  by this
>   time I get every record data from elasticsearch server what ever I have in my
>   local database. But It will show only 50 records in elasticsearch
>   browser.

Can you please help me where is the remaianing records are store. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. Your database has all the records, but the ElasticSearch browser only shows 50? It sounds like that might be a pagination limit imposed by the user interface.  A screenshot may help.